# No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [melodic]

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 docker image/container with ROS melodic and Gazebo 9 installed. When I try to run from the console within the docker container,

```
source devel/setup.bash && \
    rosdep fix-permissions && \
    rosdep update && \
    rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y --os=ubuntu:melodic
```

rosdep complains with,

```
[some package]: No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [melodic]
```

for a handful of packages.

I can successfully launch gazebo and load models but for some reason the 'rosdep install' step is failing to find gazebo.

Any ideas why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360658/no-definition-of-%5Bgazebo%5D-for-os-version-%5Bmelodic%5D/) by [joehays](https://answers.ros.org/users/3454/joehays/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have a Ubuntu 18.04 docker image/container with ROS melodic

is this the official `ros:melodic` or `osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full` container, or something custom?

In the end it doesn't really matter, as I believe the issue is this:

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y --os=ubuntu:melodic
> ```

`melodic` is not a codename for any Ubuntu release, but a ROS version, so `ubuntu:melodic` is not a legal value for `--os`.

You probably want to use `ubuntu:bionic` instead.

But since your container is based on `18.04` already, there wouldn't seem to be a need to explicitly spec the `--os`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joehays](https://answers.ros.org/users/3454/joehays/) on 2020-09-01**:
`<sheepish grin>`

changing `--os=ubuntu:melodic` to `--os=ubuntu:bionic` seemed to do it.

Thanks for catching that!

BTW: this is a custom container.